# Modify project using Jwt tokens to Oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak

I was working on a project which uses Jwt tokens for authentication and authorization, now I have a new requirement in which I have to use Oauth 2.0 for security purposes and SSO.
I wanted to know is there a way out to convert my Jwt written code to use Oauth 2.0

Comment: If you are using KeyCloak and JWT then you are already using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect I would say

Comment: Yes, I am using it but when i am trying to configure Oauth 2 in my project i m getting algorithm mismatch. I am quite new to it.

Comment: Perhaps its signing algorithm mismatch? there's quite a lot that can go wrong...?